# How to share a OneDrive document as public and allow commenting?

Tags: file-sharing, onedrive

I want to share my Word document which I uploaded on OneDrive (Windows 8.1) so that everyone can search online for it and view it. I also want to allow to everyone leaving comments but not editing the document. In Google Drive I can share a Word document as public and choose between the options: *Can Edit*, *Can Comment* or *Can View*. Am I missing something or is this still not possible in OneDrive?

[image: OneDrive sharing options]